# facebook iframe apps on mobile devices

Tags: facebook, mobile, iframe

All prior posts on this topic appear to be a year old so I am hoping for new advise or direction.

About 12-18 months ago we changed all our tabs to iframe apps for facebook but with the growing # of mobile users we need another alternative:  https://www.facebook.com/gooseberrypatch/app_250295645026932 .  Are there users or consultants available to give us direction on recreating this apps for both computer & mobile facebook use?